# Bringing Kafka data into Snowflake using Kafka Connect not preserving the decimal precision

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Kafka topic which I am trying to bring in into Snowflake via Kafka Connect. Here is a snippet of a message from the topic:

```
{
..
 "Tax": 326.6,
 "TransportValue": **11109.429999999959**,
 "Model": "2",
..
}
```

I am bringing this topic into Snowflake using Kafka Connect. When I try to query the record_content for this particular partition/offset, below is the values I see:

```
select record_content from <tablename> where partition=0 and offset=123;
```

Output:

```
RECORD_CONTENT
{
..
 "Tax": 326.6,
 "TransportValue": **11109.43**,
 "Model": "2",
..
}
```

Notice how the decimal precision was reduced from 13 places to 2 as a part of the process. Is this something that is a standard offering with Kafka Connect? How can I ensure not to lose the decimal precision of the numbers coming from the topic into Snowflake?

Any advice's are much appreciated.